# "Illegal assignment from Object" error

Tags: apex, integration, json, deserialize

```
global class CasePRBugzilla_RestService{
    global class cpb
    {
        public string Batch;
    }
    global class RecordIDS
    {
        string vmstarid {get;set;}
        string gsid {get;set;}
    }

    global class ReadPRBugResponse
    {
        List<RecordIDS> PRDetails {get;set;} 
        List<RecordIDS> BugDetails {get;set;} 
        String responseMessage {get;set;}
        String status {get;set;}
    }

    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        /**
         * this line causes error not able to save it
         */
        ReadPRBugResponse bzResponse = JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),ReadPRBugResponse.class);
        updatePRRecords(bzResponse.PRDetails);
    }


    public static void  updatePRRecords(List<RecordIDS> PRdetailsList) { 
        Set<String> gsids = new Set<String>();
        for (RecordIDS bzd:PRdetailsList) {
            gsids.add(bzd.gsid);
        }
        Map<Id, GSS_Case_BugZilla__c> PrRecordMap = new Map<Id, GSS_Case_BugZilla__c>( [ select id, VMstar_Id__c  from GSS_Case_BugZilla__c where id in:gsids]);
        for (RecordIDS  bzd : PRdetailsList) {
            PrRecordMap.get(bzd.gsid).VMstar_Id__c = bzd.vmstarid;

        }
        update PrRecordMap.values();
    }
```

It shows below error:

> Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Object to CasePRBugzilla_RestService.ReadPRBugResponse

Response:

```
{
    "prDetails":[{"gsid":"pr1gsid","vmstarid":"pr1vmstarid"},{"gsid":" pr2gsid ","vmstarid":" pr2vmstarid "}],
    "bugDetails":[{"gsid":"bugzilla1gsid","vmstarid":" bugzilla1vmstarid "},{"gsid":" bugzilla2gsid","vmstarid":" bugzilla2vmstarid"}],
    "responseMessage":"",
    "status":""
}
```

Comment: I've downvoted because you've been around long enough that I expect you to be able to format your own questions sensibly. Your provided code also will not compile because of that `if(response.statusCode == 200){..}` hanging out in the middle of your class (instead of being in a method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [JSON class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm), you'll see the following for the `deserialize()` method

> ## deserialize(jsonString, apexType)
>
> Deserializes the specified JSON string into an Apex object of the specified type.
>
> #### Signature
>
> public static Object deserialize(String jsonString, System.Type apexType)
>
> #### Parameters
>
> #### jsonString
>
> Type: String
>   The JSON content to deserialize.
>
> #### apexType
>
> Type: System.Type
>   The Apex type of the object that this method creates after deserializing the JSON content.
>
> #### Return Value
>
> Type: Object

The important bit here is those last 2 lines. You're getting an `Object` as the return value.

`Object`s pretty much always need to be explicitly type-cast to be of any use.

Your code

```
ReadPRBugResponse bzResponse = JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),ReadPRBugResponse.class);
```

does not do any type-casting. It's equivalent to

```
ReadPRBugResponse bzResponse = Object;
```

If you then look at the error message, it makes a lot of sense. "Illegal assignment from Object to CasePRBugzilla_RestService.ReadPRBugResponse"

The solution here is to type-cast the result of the deserialize call.

```
ReadPRBugResponse bzResponse = (ReadPRBugResponse)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),ReadPRBugResponse.class);
```